# How to convert from a tuple to a vec or varray in Hacklang?

Tags: hacklang

Tuple doesn't seem to implement Traversable. So, how would one convert a Tuple to a vec in Hack?

Comment: Can you not traverse it using a `foreach` loop? It seems to work for me.

`
$lst = tuple('a', 'b', 'c');
    foreach($lst as $a) {
        echo($a);
    }
`
So you can reconstruct the tuple to a vec.

Comment: Tuples aren't meant to be traversed, just indexed, so you do need to shuttle the values in manually like `vec[$tup[0], $tup[1], ...]`. Tuples are meant to be small, so this shouldn't be much of a hassle.